# How long is SPAM really good for?

Tags: meat, storage-lifetime, canning

I wanted to buy some SPAM for my zombie apocalypse survival kit, and I noticed that it had an expiration date in 2013. Should I be concerned? I've heard it will last more than 25 years.

Comment: I want a "zombie apocalypse" tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with all can goods, as long as the can has no physical defects (meaning swollen or dented, ectera), the contents should still be good. The date on the outside is mainly a best by date, after which a company will no longer vouch for the contents contained therein.

Comment: Some might argue that the contents are already bad...

Comment: @Jefromi: I find canned food is often nicer than most other "ready-made" produce.  It's been a long time since I had spam, but it's good frittered.

Comment: I was reading a book about creating a stockpile. The authors comment was that while older canned food might not be bad for you, the nutritional value is gone as well.

Comment: I would find that hard to believe as a canned good lacks the necessary bacteria or enzymes to break down the contents. What would break them down? Where would they go?

Comment: The content may not break down, but in many cases cans of food that are left past there shelf life can separate. Oil and Vinegar separate almost instantly, other foods like chili will also separate into different layers given enough time.  It would not be surprising if this happens with spam.